# PSQL: Easy way to batch select queries

Tags: postgresql, subquery, prepared-statement, wildcard, intersect

If you have table A with n columns, and a list of values with m columns where m is a subset of n, how do you query the table with one SQL statement, instead of multiple queries?

Example: users table has 4 columns:
id, name, ip, email

Example Query:

```
    SELECT * from users 
    WHERE 
        "id"=? and "name"=?
    USING VALUES
        (1, 'BOB'),
        (3, 'NOT_BOT');
```

I'm probably not using the correct search terms when looking into this but I just can't find any documentation for what seems to be a fairly simple use-case.

INTERSECT requires that both tables have the same number of columns, so I'd have to pad my existing data with "null" values, and that feels dirty. Also, what if the table changes and the number of columns is now different? A script using INTERSECT this way would be borked.

PREPARE is the most hopeful, but I'm not sure how to leverage VALUES with it, and it seems like an inefficient way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: A slight misstatement:  Intersect does not require the tables have the same number of columns. It requires the **result sets** to have the same number of columns, and compatible data types. It only requires the same number of columns in the table if you *fail to list* the desired columns in the selects. See [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=04964672334dca49423c2676f37c16b6). Result sets are not tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the IN operator:

```
SELECT * 
from users 
WHERE (id, name) in ( (1,'BOB'), (2, 'NOT_BOB') );
```

Comment: wow I knew I was overthinking this one, but not by that much.